# ng-repeat for array of objects in json

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I had been trying to display objects fields like `name`, `address` in a table from a remote JSON file. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. `ng-repeat` only works when i index the iterator.

```
angular.module('mainApp', [])
.controller('branchListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://some.url.com')
  .then(function(response) {              
    $scope.artists = response.data;
    console.log($scope.artists);
  });
});

<tr ng-repeat="x in artists"> 
  <td>{{x.name}}</td> <!--this only gives empty rows equal to # of objectsin json-->
  <td>{{x.address}}</td>
</tr>    
<tr ng-repeat="x in artists">
  <td>{{x[1].name}}</td>
  <td>{{x[1].address}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: add the json structure

Comment: {  
   "success":"yes",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "parent_retailer":1,
         "name":"dummy",
         "address":"1234d",
         "status":true,
         "geo_location":{  
            "x":24.321,
            "y":74.102
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "parent_retailer":1,
         "name":"dummy2",
         "address":"fdsds",
         "status":true,
         "geo_location":{  
            "x":24.321,
            "y":74.102
         }
      },
     
   ],
   "error_code":"",
   "error_description":""
}

Comment: Study your JSON. 
Probably use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to restructure (beautify) your JSON and then understand its structure. You will get your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in controller it should be:

`$scope.artists = response.data.data;`

Comment: This worked! Thanks a bunch.. and how would I access the 'geo-location' object inside the object or an array inside the object?

Comment: Example : `{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "dummy",
  "address": "1234d",
  "geo_location": {
    "x": 24.321,
    "y": 74.102
  },
  "dummy_array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}`
you can access it using key like `x.geo-location` or `x.dummy-array`. You can again use ng-repeat for iterating array.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the .data . Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="artist in artists.data"> 
   <td>{{artist.name}}</td>
     <td>{{artist.address}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){

$scope.datas = {"success":"yes", "data":[ { "id":"1", "parent_retailer":1, "name":"dummy", "address":"1234d", "status":true, "geo_location":{ "x":24.321, "y":74.102 } }, { "id":"2", "parent_retailer":1, "name":"dummy2", "address":"fdsds", "status":true, "geo_location":{ "x":24.321, "y":74.102 } }, ], "error_code":"", "error_description":"" };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="dat in datas.data">
{{dat.id}} {{dat.name}} {{dat.address}}  {{dat.geo_location.x}}
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Json objects You need to use key value in `ng-repeat`

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in artists"> 
 <td>{{key}}</td> 
 <td>{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

You can take reference here : 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. No need to put extra **`ng-repeat`**

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.artists = [{
 "id": "1",
 "parent_retailer": 1,
 "name": "dummy",
 "address": "1234d",
 "status": true,
 "geo_location": {
  "x": 24.321,
  "y": 74.102
 }
}, {
 "id": "2",
 "parent_retailer": 1,
 "name": "dummy2",
 "address": "fdsds",
 "status": true,
 "geo_location": {
  "x": 24.321,
  "y": 74.102
 }
}];
});
```

```css
table,tr,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in artists"> 
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.address}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```